# Specific How-To Minimally Style XML with XSLT after adding over-arching categories

Tags: xml, xslt, styling

So I'm going through the XML tutorial on w3schools, and I come across this page about styling XML with XSLT:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=simple&xsltfile=simple

There's some simply code there. I added two over-arching food categories `<waffles>` and `<other>`
to the code, and I was wondering how I could use minimal XSLT to style the XML so that all `<waffle> <food>` have a orange background and all `<other><food>` to have a cyan background, without having to repeat a large chunk of code like I did below.

You can see the original code in the link above, here's my code:

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<breakfast_menu>
     <waffles>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$8.95</price>
        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
     </waffles>
     <other>
    <food>
        <name>French Toast</name>
        <price>$4.50</price>
        <description>thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
        <calories>600</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
        <price>$6.95</price>
        <description>two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
        <calories>950</calories>
    </food>
     <other>
</breakfast_menu>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
    <html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
    <xsl:for-each select="breakfast_menu/waffles">
        <div style="background-color:ORANGE;">
          <xsl:for-each select="food">
          <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
            <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></span>
            - <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
          </div>
          <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
            <span style="font-style:italic">
              <xsl:value-of select="calories"/> (calories per serving)
            </span>
          </div>
         </xsl:for-each>
       </div>    
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="breakfast_menu/other">
        <div style="background-color:CYAN;">
          <xsl:for-each select="food">
          <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
            <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></span>
            - <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
          </div>
          <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
            <span style="font-style:italic">
              <xsl:value-of select="calories"/> (calories per serving)
            </span>
          </div>
         </xsl:for-each>
       </div>    
    </xsl:for-each>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If the tutorial told you to use `xsl:for-each` for this, then it's badly broken and you should avoid it.  That's procedural 'pull' XSLT, which goes against the design of XSLT.  Read about 'pull' vs 'push' styles.  I've always heard bad things about w3schools, and the little I've seen of it has been mediocre at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you can make use of the power of templates, one of the most fundamental concepts of XSLT.

You can start by looking for the child elements of the **breakfast_menu** elements

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="breakfast_menu/*"/>
```

Then you would have a template to match such elements

```
<xsl:template match="breakfast_menu/*">
```

In this template you could then use an **xsl:choose** to create the style attribute

```
  <div>
     <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'waffles'">background-color:ORANGE;</xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'other'">background-color:CYAN;</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:attribute>
```

Here is the full XSLT in this case. Note is also uses templates to match the **food** element to avoid the use of **xsl:for-each**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="breakfast_menu/*"/>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="breakfast_menu/*">
      <div>
         <xsl:attribute name="style">
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'waffles'">background-color:ORANGE;</xsl:when>
               <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'other'">background-color:CYAN;</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="food"/>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="food">
      <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
         <span style="font-weight:bold">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
         </span> - 
         <xsl:value-of select="price"/></div>
      <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
         <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
         <span style="font-style:italic">
            <xsl:value-of select="calories"/> (calories per serving) </span>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Another slightly different approach, to avoid the use of **xsl:choose** is to have separate templates to match your **waffle** and **other** elements. Just replace the current template that matches "breakfast_menu/*" with the following two templates.

```
<xsl:template match="breakfast_menu/waffles">
  <div style="background-color:ORANGE;">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="food"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="breakfast_menu/other">
  <div style="background-color:CYAN;">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="food"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

And if you had lots of child elements, but wanted a default 'value' you could do something like this

```
<xsl:template match="breakfast_menu/waffles" priority="2">
  <div style="background-color:ORANGE;">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="food"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="breakfast_menu/*" priority="1">
  <div style="background-color:CYAN;">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="food"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the use of the **priority** attribute in this case, because both templates would match **waffle** otherwise. This would be an error unless you told the XSLT processor that one had a higher priority than the other.

Comment: After reading about push vs. pull as suggested by Jim the first two parts make a bunch of sense to me. Thanks. Well written and fantastic that you gave three options. It took me a while but I think I got what you meant with the priority method -- I'm guessing the lower number is higher priority, right?

Comment: The higher the number, the higher the priority. In this case you want the 'beakfast_menu/waffles' template to be used for waffles, rather than the more generic 'breakfast_menu/*' one, which also matches it.

Comment: Ah ok. It makes sense that way too.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:colors>
  <color>ORANGE</color>
  <color>CYAN</color>
 </my:colors>

 <xsl:variable name="vColors" select="document('')/*/my:colors/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[food]">
        <div style="background-color:{$vColors[2 -(name(current())='waffles')]};">
          <xsl:for-each select="food">
          <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
            <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></span>
            - <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
          </div>
          <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
            <span style="font-style:italic">
              <xsl:value-of select="calories"/> (calories per serving)
            </span>
          </div>
         </xsl:for-each>
       </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<breakfast_menu>
     <waffles>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$8.95</price>
        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
     </waffles>
     <other>
    <food>
        <name>French Toast</name>
        <price>$4.50</price>
        <description>thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
        <calories>600</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
        <price>$6.95</price>
        <description>two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
        <calories>950</calories>
    </food>
     </other>
</breakfast_menu>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
      <div xmlns="" style="background-color:ORANGE;">
         <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
            <span style="font-weight:bold">Belgian Waffles</span>
            - $5.95</div>
         <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup<span style="font-style:italic">650 (calories per serving)
            </span>
         </div>
         <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
            <span style="font-weight:bold">Strawberry Belgian Waffles</span>
            - $7.95</div>
         <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream<span style="font-style:italic">900 (calories per serving)
            </span>
         </div>
         <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
            <span style="font-weight:bold">Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</span>
            - $8.95</div>
         <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream<span style="font-style:italic">900 (calories per serving)
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div xmlns="" style="background-color:CYAN;">
         <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
            <span style="font-weight:bold">French Toast</span>
            - $4.50</div>
         <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread<span style="font-style:italic">600 (calories per serving)
            </span>
         </div>
         <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
            <span style="font-weight:bold">Homestyle Breakfast</span>
            - $6.95</div>
         <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns<span style="font-style:italic">950 (calories per serving)
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of:

1. **[Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#rules)** matching.
2. [**AVT**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)s (Attribute Value Templates).